# Avoid multiple connections to mongoDB from spark streaming

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We developed a spark streaming application that sources data from kafka and writes to mongoDB. We are noticing performance implications while creating connections inside foreachRDD on the input DStream. The spark streaming application does a few validations before inserting into mongoDB. We are exploring options to avoid connecting to mongoDB for each message that is processed, rather we desire to process all messages within one batch interval at once. Following is the simplified version of the spark streaming application. One of the things we did is append all the messages to a dataframe and try inserting the contents of that dataframe outside of the foreachRDD. But when we run this application, the code that writes dataframe to mongoDB does not get executed.

Please note that I commented out a part of the code inside foreachRDD which we used to insert each message into mongoDB. Existing approach is very slow as we are inserting one message at a time. Any suggestions on performance improvement is much appreciated.

Thank you

```
package com.testing

import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ SQLContext, Row, Column, DataFrame }
import java.util.HashMap
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord }
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import com.mongodb.util.JSON

import scala.io.Source._
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.Calendar

import scala.collection.immutable
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats


object Sample_Streaming {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample_Streaming")
      .setMaster("local[4]")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

    val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()


    val bootstrap_server_config = "127.0.0.100:9092"
    val zkQuorum = "127.0.0.101:2181"



    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap_server_config)
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

    val TopicMap = Map("sampleTopic" -> 1)
    val KafkaDstream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "group", TopicMap).map(_._2)

      val schemaDf = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
        .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "connectionURI")
        .option("spark.mongodb.input.collection", "schemaCollectionName")
        .load()

      val outSchema = schemaDf.schema
      var outDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], outSchema)

    KafkaDstream.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.collect().map { x =>
      {
        val jsonInput: JValue = parse(x)


        /*Do all the transformations using Json libraries*/

        val json4s_transformed = "transformed json"

        val rdd = sc.parallelize(compact(render(json4s_transformed)) :: Nil)
        val df = sqlContext.read.schema(outSchema).json(rdd)

 //Earlier we were inserting each message into mongoDB, which we would like to avoid and process all at once       
/*        df.write.option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "connectionURI")
                  .option("collection", "Collection")
                  .mode("append").format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").save()*/
        outDf = outDf.union(df)

      }

    }

    )


      //Added this part of the code in expectation to access the unioned dataframe and insert all messages at once
      //println(outDf.count())
      if(outDf.count() > 0)
      {
        outDf.write
                  .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "connectionURI")
                  .option("collection", "Collection")
                  .mode("append").format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").save()
      }


    // Run the streaming job
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused by "we desire to process all messages within the DStream at once". DStreams are infinite... do you mean to process all messages within one batch interval at once?

Comment: Yes I meant to process all messages within one batch interval at once. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would want to reduce the number of connections to `mongodb`, for this purpose, you must use `foreachPartition` in code when you serve connection do mongodb see [spec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachPartitionFunction), the code will look like this:

```
rdd.repartition(1).foreachPartition {
    //get instance of connection
    //write/read with batch to mongo
    //close connection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will try it out.